# Grails Unit Test doesn't fail

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am trying to perform basic unit test on a Grails domain class.

Here is the domain class:

```
class User {
    String username
    String password
    String email

    static constraints = {
        username size: 4..15, blank: false, unique: true
        password size: 5..15, password: true, blank: false
        email email: true, blank: false
    }
}
```

Here is the unit test class:

```
@TestFor(User)
class UserTests {
    void testCreateUser() {
        def u = new User(username:"ab")
        assertFalse "There should be errors", u.validate()
        assertTrue "Should be errors here", u.hasErrors()
    }
}
```

`username` is constrained by size from 4 to 15. However, when I run `grails test-app` the above test succeeds. I don't understand why the constraint isn't causing it to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't write which Grails version you use, but generally you should set up User class to be tested for constraint checks. Add this to your UserTests

```
def setUp() {
    mockForConstraintsTests(User)
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what difference does Grail version makes? Do different Grails versions have different Unit Tests definitions? Thank you.

Comment: @MeIr put `mockForConstraintsTests(User)` line as the first line of `testCreateUser` and see if it succeeds.